# Advice for hand-written olap-like extractions from relational database

Tags: sql, olap

We've implemented over the course of the years a series of web based reports summarizing historical business data (product sales, traffic, etc). The thing relies heavily on complex SQL queries, and the boss expects the results to be real time, but they need up to a minute to execute. The reports are customizable on a several dimensions.

I've done some basic research, and it looks like what we need is some kind of OLAP (?), ETL(?), whatever.

Is that true? Are we supposed to convert to a whole package and trash our beloved developments, or is there a possibility to keep it relational, SQL-based, and get close to a dedicated solution by simply pre-calculating some optimized views with a batch process running at night? Have you got pointers to good documentation on the subject?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do ETL (Extract, transform, and load) at night, loading the (probably summarized) data into tables that can usually be queried pretty quickly.  Appropriate indexes are still important.

It often makes sense to put those summary tables in a different schema, a different database, or on a different server, but you don't absolutely *have* to do that.

The structure of the tables is important, and it's not like designing tables for an OLTP system. The IBM Redbooks have a couple of titles that can help you design the tables.

- [Data Modeling Techniques for Data
  Warehousing](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg242238.html?Open)
- [Dimensional Modeling: In a Business
  Intelligence Environment](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247138.html?Open)

Most dbms today support SQL analytic functions. See, for example, [Analytic Functions by Example](http://orafaq.com/node/55) for Oracle, or [Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you for your kind responses. Are you so caring people in real life too, or you do all for the points and the badges? :)

Comment: Some people answer questions for the points and badges. I just like to answer questions. Making things work takes a certain amount of understanding. But explaining things clearly takes a lot more understanding.  Answering questions makes me better at what I do.

Answer (score 0):

In the long term, it sounds as though a move to a data warehouse would definitely benefit you (as suggested in Catcall's answer). You can use the existing reports as a starting point for your data warehouse's requirements.

In the short term, you *could* build summarised tables optimised for your existing reporting requirements. This should probably be regarded as a stopgap, unless you are never going to change these reports again.

You might also benefit from looking into partitioning tables in your database by date/time, since you will probably still want to report the current day's data for realtime reporting purposes.

Comment: Thank you. Abouot your last point: tables are already partitioned, kindof, meaning that in some cases there is one different *table* per day (!).

Comment: Ouch! In most RDBMSs, it's possible to partition tables *internally* by values, so that you get the performance advantages of separate tables with the convenience of a single table.